Unable to instantiate fragment com.swmansion.rnscreens.ScreenFragment
I have the following problem when try test on Play Store: ╔
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.piero2906.ororosso/com.piero2906.ororosso.MainActivity}: androidx.fragment.app.Fragment$j: Unable to instantiate fragment com.swmansion.rnscreens.ScreenFragment: calling Fragment constructor caused an exception

The repo is : https://github.com/pierre1590/Report-cherries
I tried reinstalling react-native-screens, but I hve the same problem.
